# System Image Backup & Recovery - on a new Disk

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, images, system-restore

The harddisk on my laptop is going to be replaced with a new Harddisk under warranty because of some problems. My laptop came with Windows 8, which I free upgraded to Windows 8.1 & then to Windows 10.

I have 2 questions

1) If I make a System Image Backup from Windows Control Panel, will I be able to restore it to the new disk.
http://www.howtogeek.com/239312/how-to-restore-system-image-backups-on-windows-7-8-and-10/

This says I cannot restore to a different machine - but is the same machine with a different harddisk be considered as a different machine?

2) My Control Panel shows the item "Backup & Recovery(Windows 7)". Does this mean if I restore - it will restore it to Windows 7 rather than Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Yes it will work, and you can restore an image of windows 10 to a new hard drive with the "
Backup and Recovery (Windows 7)" tool

The whole point of a system image is to be able to restore if your disk dies or otherwise goes nuts. Yes, it should work, assuming the backup's fine.

As for the whole "backup and recovery (windows 7)" - windows 8 and up use a different, purely file based backup system that assumes you can install windows from a dvd and restore. And MS was all funny about the old, awesome, image based backup method being legacy and gave it a clunky name. It will restore whatever you're running.

So yes, the usual bits about testing your backups in mind, yes, it should work exactly as you expect it to

Comment: `As for the whole "backup and recovery (windows 7)" - windows 8 and up use a different, purely file based backup system that assumes you can install windows from a dvd and restore.` - I don't understand - do I need to install windows from a DVD? I don't have a DVD with Windows installable

Comment: backup and recovery would work bare metal without the need to install with the recovery disk it generates. And with 10, I believe there's a way to generate a installer from either the tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10) or downloading an ISO from them

Comment: I really don't understand your answer at all. Neither the original one nor the one in the comments.

Comment: TLDR: It'll work.

Comment: Will it give me "Windows 10" after restore? Why is the Backup and Restore on my Windows 10 called Backup and Restore (Windows 7)?

Comment: Yes. It's called that cause it's the backup and restore system from Windows 7, but it'll image and restore your windows 10 install fine

Comment: Also, the new harddisk will not make the machine to be considered as a new machine - i.e. disallow restore on it?

Comment: Yes. Totally. This is the *precise* scenario backups are for after all